# preg_replace, target shorter than x characters, except numbers

Tags: php, regex

I'm modifying an existing line of code that uses preg_replace

```
$string = preg_replace('/(?<=\s)[^\s]{1,'.$x.'}(?=\s)/Su', ' ', $string);
```

My basic understanding is that this replaces words with less than $x characters with a space. I've searched for regex examples to do the same thing, but they look a lot different. Can someone briefly explain what this particular regex does exactly?

Anyway, what I want to modify is basically make it work as is except to exclude numbers. So that single digit numbers will not be replaced by the space.

thanks

Comment: So, if you have `"Id: 4"` you want to get `"  4"`? Without more details, taking into account what you wrote, perhaps, `'/(?<!\S)(?!\d(?!\S))\S{1,'.$x.'}(?!\S)/u'` will work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes. if the min-character was 4, sure.

Comment: So, does the suggestion above work?

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone briefly explain what this particular regex does exactly?

**Regex:** `(?<=\s)[^\s]{1,'.$x.'}(?=\s)`

**Explanation:**

`(?<=\s)` Lookbehind for whitespace and match zerowidth. Such as `a |b` where `|` depicting zero width.

`[^\s]{1,'.$x.'}` Match non whitespace characters 1 to $x no of times. Could had used `\S`, same thing.

`(?=\s)` Lookahead for a whitespace and match zeros width so that previously matched non whitespace characters should be followed by a whitespace. Such as `a| b`.